# I want to learn the inbuilt classes and methods in java libraries? please guide

Tags: java, javadoc

Please give some to-do task and techniques to learn inbuilt classes and methods in packages! I want to became a successful java developer!

Comment: If you use Intellij ctrl + click will take you to the source code of any method/class. All IDEs will have a similar way

Comment: Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read the *source* for Java 8 for all the classes in these packages.

- java.lang
- java.io
- java.util
- java.util.concurrent

optionally I suggest

- java.nio
- java.math
- java.sql
- java.time

If you understand this code, you will know more than many senior developers.

You can read them in your IDE by search for them or writing a simple test which uses them can use `<ctrl>` + `<click>`

Comment: Maybe read the api to begin with instead of going straight to source

Comment: @Ronan possibly, though reading the code would teach you a lot about Java which is good for a beginner.

Comment: For a beginner I would suggest being able to use the tools first then when they are comfortable with them then learn how they work. I do believe when getting out of the beginner stage is when you should start looking at how they work though. This is just my opinion and I know other ways work for other people

Comment: What means the source of java 8??

Comment: @KushalMaharana I means the Source of the libraries above for the latest version of Java. It comes with the JDK or you can search for it those classes on the internet.